# spaCy or language model en_core_web_sm is not installed in any of python executables

Tags: r, nlp, spacy

Trying to get spacyr up and running. Have installed miniconda in zsh (osx teminal) and am running the following:

```
devtools::install_github("kbenoit/spacyr", build_vignettes = FALSE)
spacy_download_langmodel("en_core_web_lg")


library("spacyr")
spacy_initialize(model = "en_core_web_sm")
```

I think install is ok, but language model is not downloading. Throws following errors:

> spacy_download_langmodel("en_core_web_lg")
> Error in spacy_download_langmodel("en_core_web_lg") :
> could not find function "spacy_download_langmodel"
> library("spacyr")
> spacy_initialize(model = "en_core_web_sm")
> Finding a python executable with spaCy installed...
> Error in set_spacy_python_option(python_executable, virtualenv, condaenv,  :
> spaCy or language model en_core_web_sm is not installed in any of python executables.

Am I missing something, should I be downloading the language models elsewhere? I thought installing through r self contains the env etc.

Apologies new to spacyr and nlp. Any feedback appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Hadn't installed language model through terminal. This did the trick:

```
python -m spacy download en
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the system, Pyhton package management etc., the commands may vary, and other preparations may be necessary.

On https://spacy.io/usage/ you can click together the lines to install `spacyr`. Here's the default example:

```
pip install -U pip setuptools wheel
pip install -U spacy
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

Note, that the installation is per-user. And maybe you'll need a `apt install python-is-python3` for the `python` command to be accepted.